# WCF use service from other project in solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, wcf

I was trying to replicate the [Ajax Service without configuration sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb472534(v=vs.110).aspx) from Microsoft. The only difference is that I placed my service in a separate project.

Now I'd like to know how I can access that service in my website project.
My solution looks like this: [image: solution]

But when I try to add the service reference to the Script Manager it won't let me.[image: urlpicker]

What am I doing wrong here? Can I just not do that? Am I missing something?

There has to be a simple way to do this right?

Comment: Where is `.svc` file ?

Comment: You need to start both projects to do it. Are you using IIS or IIS Express and both are started? Your service project does not look to be a wcf web project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need another application, to host your service

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/784084/WCF-Self-Hosting-in-a-Console-Application-Simplifi

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/650869/Creating-a-Self-Hosted-WCF-Service

after hosting your service, you can add service reference from UserSite Project

Comment: Thanks, I guess they just don't have tools to host it in a debug environment when you're running it in the same project. That might be handy though...